# Return Active Directory for group members with attributes with C# .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, active-directory, ldap

I need to retrieve certain attributes from members of a given group in Active Directory and I think I'm on the wrong track.

My current LDAP query looks like this:

```
(&(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={DN for group})(objectClass=user)(objectCategory={objectCategory}))
```

This is a rather heavy query, which in average takes 10 - 20 seconds regardless of the result contains 0, 1 or a 1000 users. The result can be replicated in C# and powershell (Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter {Your filter})

A colleague of mine proposed implementing something similar to this powershell query

```bsh
$group = "{samAccountName}"

$attributes = "employeeId","sn","givenName","telephoneNumber","mobile","hPRnr","cn","samAccountName","gender","company","reshId"

Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Get-ADUser -Properties $attributes | select $attributes
```

Is it possible to use the api available in C# to implement the powershell query somehow or is there a better solution?

To clearify.
I have a C# approach today which has an emphasis on LDAP. The average perfomance is between 10 - 15 seconds whether there are 0 or 1000 members in the AD group.

A complete example of how the code works with the following libraries added to the project:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore
Newtonsoft.Json
System.DirectoryServices
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ActiveDirectoryLibrary.Standard.Services
{
    public class LdapService
    {
        private ILogger _logger;
        private string PersonCategory = "ObjectCategoryForUser";

        public LdapService(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public List<User> GetUserRecordsInNestedGroupDetailed(string nestedGroup, string ou)
        {
            var groupStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            groupStopwatch.Start();
            var group = GetGroup(nestedGroup, ou);
            groupStopwatch.Stop();
            _logger.LogDebug(
                $"Method {nameof(GetUserRecordsInNestedGroupDetailed)}: Getting the group {nestedGroup} took {groupStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

            if (group == null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.DistinguishedName)) return new List<User>();

            //PersonCategory is the object category for a user object in Active Directory

            var ldapFilter =
                $"(&(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={group.DistinguishedName})(objectClass=user)(objectCategory={PersonCategory}))";
            var groupMembers = new List<User>();

            using (var adsEntry = new DirectoryEntry())
            {
                using (var ds = new DirectorySearcher(adsEntry))
                {
                    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                    stopwatch.Start();
                    ds.Filter = ldapFilter;
                    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                    LoadAdUserProperties(ds);
                    var members = ds.FindAll();
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    _logger.LogDebug(
                        $"Method {nameof(GetUserRecordsInNestedGroupDetailed)}: Time consumed {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms for {group.DistinguishedName}");
                    foreach (SearchResult sr in members)
                    {
                        groupMembers.Add(MapSearchResultToUser(sr));
                    }
                }
            }

            return groupMembers;
        }

        public Group GetGroup(string samAccountName, string ou)
        {
            using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{ou}"))
            {
                var ds = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
                {
                    Filter = "(&(objectcategory=group)(SamAccountName=" + samAccountName + "))"
                };
                var group = ds.FindOne();
                return group == null ? null : MapSearchResultToGroup(group);
            }
        }

        public static Group MapSearchResultToGroup(SearchResult @group)
        {
            var returnGroup = new Group
            {
                Changed = GetProperty<DateTime>(@group, "whenchanged"),
                SamAccountName = GetProperty<string>(group, "SamAccountName"),
                Description = GetProperty<string>(group, "Description"),
                Created = GetProperty<DateTime>(group, "whencreated"),
                DistinguishedName = GetProperty<string>(group, "distinguishedname"),
                Name = GetProperty<string>(group, "name")
            };
            return returnGroup;
        }

        private static void LoadAdUserProperties(DirectorySearcher ds)
        {
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("reshid");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("employeeid");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("gender");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephonenumber");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mobile");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("companyname");
        }

        public static User MapSearchResultToUser(SearchResult userProperty)
        {

            var reshId = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "reshid");
            var employeeElement = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "employeeid");
            var surname = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "sn");
            var givenname = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "givenname");
            var gender = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "gender");
            var phone = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "telephonenumber");
            var mobile = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "mobile");
            var hpr = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "hprnr");
            var cn = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "cn");
            var samAccountName = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "samaccountname");
            var company = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "company");
            var account = new User
            {
                EmployeeId = employeeElement,
                Sn = surname,
                GivenName = givenname,
                Gender = gender,
                Telephone = phone,
                Mobile = mobile,
                Cn = cn,
                SamAccountName = samAccountName,
                Company = company,
                ReshId = reshId
            };
            return account;
        }

        private static T GetProperty<T>(SearchResult userProperty, string key)
        {
            if (userProperty.Properties[key].Count == 1)
            {
                return (T) userProperty.Properties[key][0];
            }

            return default(T);
        }

        public class Group
        {
            public DateTime Changed { get; set; }
            public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime Created { get; set; }
            public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class User
        {
            public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
            public string Sn { get; set; }
            public string GivenName { get; set; }
            public string Telephone { get; set; }
            public string OfficePhone { get; set; }
            public string Mobile { get; set; }
            public string Mail { get; set; }
            public string Cn { get; set; }
            public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            public string Company { get; set; }
            public string ReshId { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to query the group hierarchy recursively, or are you only interested in direct members of the group?

Comment: Tough question. In worst case scenario this is a nested group, so I believe I have to search the entire tree and not just the first layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written about this in an article I wrote about [finding members of a group](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/11/30/find-all-members-of-group.html), since group membership can be an oddly complicated thing sometimes. But here is a method that I put there that will likely be good enough for your case.

I've modified it to return a `User` object like you are in your code. If you pass `true` for the `recursive` parameter, it will traverse nested groups. You should be able to modify it to suit your needs.

```
public static IEnumerable<User> GetGroupMemberList(DirectoryEntry group, bool recursive = false) {
    var members = new List<User>();

    group.RefreshCache(new[] { "member" });

    while (true) {
        var memberDns = group.Properties["member"];
        foreach (string member in memberDns) {
            using (var memberDe = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{member.Replace("/", "\\/")}")) {
                memberDe.RefreshCache(new[] { "objectClass", "samAccountName", "mail", "mobile" });

                if (recursive && memberDe.Properties["objectClass"].Contains("group")) {
                    members.AddRange(GetGroupMemberList(memberDe, true));
                } else {
                    members.Add(new User {
                        SamAccountName = (string) memberDe.Properties["samAccountName"].Value,
                        Mail = (string) memberDe.Properties["mail"].Value,
                        Mobile = (string) memberDe.Properties["mobile"].Value,
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        if (memberDns.Count == 0) break;

        try {
            group.RefreshCache(new[] {$"member;range={members.Count}-*"});
        } catch (COMException e) {
            if (e.ErrorCode == unchecked((int) 0x80072020)) { //no more results
                break;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
    return members;
}
```

You do have to pass it a `DirectoryEntry` object for the group. If you already have the DN of the group, you can create it like this:

```
new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{dn.Replace("/", "\\/")}")
```

If you don't, you can find the group by its `sAMAccountName` like this:

```
var groupSamAccountName = "MyGroup";
var ds = new DirectorySearcher($"(sAMAccountName={groupSamAccountName})") {
    PropertiesToLoad = { "cn" } //just to stop it from returning every attribute
};
var groupDirectoryEntry = ds.FindOne()?.GetDirectoryEntry();

var members = GetGroupMemberList(groupDirectoryEntry, false); //pass true if you want recursive members
```

There is other code in my article for finding members from external trusted domains (if you have any trusted domains) and for finding users who have the group as their primary group, since the primary group relationship isn't visible in the group's `member` attribute.

To use this code in .NET Core, you need to install the [Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility/2.0.0-preview1-25914-04) NuGet package to be able to use the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace. This will limit you to only being able to run your application on Windows. If you need to run your app on non-Windows operating systems, you can look into the [Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/), but I can't help there.

Comment: As good as it can get for the information you need. The time it takes will depend on how big the group is. If you need to change it, I wrote another article about getting [better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html) when coding with AD. It's really easy to get bad performance if you're not careful.

Comment: I didn't get a decent enough performance with your proposal, so I created a solution based on both PrincipalContext from AccountManagment and on LDAP from DirectoryServices to query AD. It seems like with AccountManagment and DirectoryServices, it's either or when it comes to which properties are available and how well they perform. I've even checked out the Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.dll (which Powershell uses) to see if there was anything quick and easy to use, but I quickly dismissed the idea since the API is targeted at Powershell rather than accessing it through C#.

Comment: I'm curious to see your solution. The `AccountManagement` namespace is just a wrapper around `DirectoryServices`, so there is nothing you can do with `AccountManagement` that you can't do with `DirectoryServices`. For that same reason, you can always get faster performance by using `DirectoryServices` directly - it just depends on how you are using it.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, my solution is the answer below. For some reason I got it be quicker by using the wrapper along with DirectoryServices.

Answer (score 0):

Since my current answer diverges heavily from Gabriel Lucis, I figured it be better to propose what I came up with:

```
    public IEnumerable<User> GetContactDetailsForGroupMembersWithPrincipalContext(string samAccountName, string ou, bool recursive)
    {
        var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        var grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, samAccountName);
        var users = new List<User>();

        if (grp != null)
        {
            foreach (var principal in grp.GetMembers(true))
            {
                var member = (UserPrincipal) principal;
                var user = GetUser(member);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    users.Add(user);
                }
            }
        }

        return users;
    }

    private User GetUser(UserPrincipal member)
    {
        var entry = (DirectoryEntry) member.GetUnderlyingObject();
        var search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mobile");
        var result = search.FindOne();
        var user = MapSearchResultToUser(result);
        return user;
    }

    public static User MapSearchResultToUser(SearchResult userProperty)
    {
        var mobile = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "mobile");
        var mail = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "mail");
        var samAccountName = GetProperty<string>(userProperty, "samaccountname");

        var account = new User
        {
            Mobile = mobile,
            Mail = mail,
            SamAccountName = samAccountName,
        };
        return account;
    }

    private static T GetProperty<T>(SearchResult userProperty, string key)
    {
        if (userProperty.Properties[key].Count == 1)
        {
            return (T)userProperty.Properties[key][0];
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

The average performance up to 50 members is about 500 to 1000 ms. The Code does not scale very well, a nested group with 1079 members had in average 13 000 ms.

The reason why I have to query AD two times:

1. Find the AD Group to get the group members
2. Get custom properties from the User which are not available in the UserPrincipal object.

Comment: I have a hard time believing this performs faster :) I updated the code in my answer to return a `User` object like you are, and added code to show you how to find a group by name using `DirectorySearcher`. Test that out.

Comment: But also, this new code you posted isn't equivalent to the code in your question. Your original code was searching for members recursively. This new code isn't. If you don't need the recursive members, just remove the `:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:` from your original code, and that would probably be faster than anything else. But it won't get members from other domains, if there are any.

Comment: And in this new code, you don't need to use `DirectorySearcher` to find the account again. Just use `entry.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value`. That's adding one new network request for every member.

Comment: Testing Gabriel answer now, took a while to get what you are doing since my original intention was to do most of the work through LDAP. However, I underestimated how taxing recursive searches are. I got a little blind as well from looking at how Powershells Get-AdGroupMember works out of the box.

I have tested with two nested groups that has over 7000 members in it. My original code is limited to 1000 entries (by default, but can be limited), while Gabriels code loops until it's done. Is it possible to find the size of a nested group?

Comment: Would it make sense to validate a group, to make sure it's not a nested group?

Comment: All of this does use LDAP to communicate with AD. AD only gives you 1000 or 1500 at a time (depending on the version), so you do have to be aware of that and ask for the next block. The only way to determine the size is to go through all of them. The size isn't stored separately anywhere. The group's `member` attribute stores the `distinguishedName`, so if you want, you could just count those (and store them in a `List<string>`) before you go back out to AD and get the details of each. Likewise, the only way to determine if it's a nested group is to look at each member too see if it's a group.